# VJet and Javascript IDE it's possible to integrate the two

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, vjet

I installed VJet as plugin and it is nice that i can have JQuery autocomplete using the 'VJet editor" view, but i'm using the javascript IDE (downloaded at eclipse.org) and it's nice too because i can do auto complete in objects like array and i can have syntax coloring and others thing. but i can archive this with the "JavaScript editor" view. then was thinking if there is some way to integrate the power of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the two editors are different.

(Disclaimer)I am the lead on the VJET project and looking for ways to improve. The VJET editor is a newly open source project and the team is looking for feedback. I recommend going to the VJET project forum and asking for features.

It would also be great for VJET to work with the eclipse JavaScript project (JSDT). Most of the energy of that project is going towards debugging and the JavaScript editor Orion.

Comment: Follow up VJET is becoming part of eclipse webtools project - http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/webtools.vjet/

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was, but there is no magical way to integrate two different editors in eclipse.

Every editor is defined to provide syntax highlighting, code assist and more in a specific way. One way to have all the features in one is to create an editor that extends another (...and I simplified it a lot...).

The best I can recommend is to use an editor that can support both. I admit, I am biased... but you can try Aptana Studio (which is based on Eclipse).